# Slicing NetCDF variable using bounding box subset

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, netcdf, netcdf4

**Background**

I am attempting to slice a NetCDF file using a bounding box of lat/lons. The relevant information of this file is listed below (variables, shape, dimensions):

[image]

Per most answers here and standard tutorials, this should be very straightforward, and my interpretation is that you just find the indices of the lat/lons and slice the variable array by those indices.

**Attempt/Code**

```
 def netcdf_worker(nc_file, bbox):
    dataset = Dataset(nc_file)
    for variable in dataset.variables.keys():
        if (variable != 'lat') and (variable != 'lon'):
            var_name = variable
            break

    # Full extent of data
    lats = dataset.variables['lat'][:]
    lons = dataset.variables['lon'][:]

    if bbox:
        lat_bnds = [bbox[0], bbox[2]]  # min lat, max lat
        lon_bnds = [bbox[1], bbox[3]]  # min lon, max lon
        lat_inds = np.where((lats > lat_bnds[0]) & (lats < lat_bnds[1]))
        lon_inds = np.where((lons > lon_bnds[0]) & (lons < lon_bnds[1]))

        var_subset = dataset.variables[var_name][:, lat_inds[0], lon_inds[0]]

        # would also be great to slice the lats and lons too for visualization
```

**Problem**

When attempting to implement the solutions found in other answers listed on SO via the above code, I am met with the error:

```
File "/Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/Viewer/viewer.py", line 41, in netcdf_worker
    var_subset = dataset.variables[var_name][:, lat_inds[0], lon_inds[0]]
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 4095, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__getitem__
  File "/Users/XXXXXX/Viewer/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netCDF4/utils.py", line 242, in _StartCountStride
    ea = np.where(ea < 0, ea + shape[i], ea)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I believe there is something minor I am missing/not understanding about slicing multidimensional arrays and would appreciate any help. I am not interested in any solutions that bring any other packages or operate external to python (no CDO or NCKS answers please!). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, I think that the easiest solution is to use `xarray`. Minimal example (using some ERA5 data):

```
import xarray as xr

f = xr.open_dataset('model_fc.nc')

print(f['latitude'].values)  # [52.771 52.471 52.171 51.871 51.571 51.271 50.971]
print(f['longitude'].values) # [3.927 4.227 4.527 4.827 5.127 5.427 5.727]

f2 = f.sel(longitude=slice(4.5, 5.4), latitude=slice(52.45, 51.5))  

print(f2['latitude'].values)  # [52.171 51.871 51.571]
print(f2['longitude'].values) # [4.527 4.827 5.127]
```

As an example I'm only showing the `latitude` and `longitude` variables, but all variables in the NetCDF file which have `latitude` and `longitude` dimensions are sliced automatically.

---

Alternatively, if you want to select the box manually (using NetCDF4):

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
import numpy as np

f = nc4.Dataset('model_fc.nc')

lat = f.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = f.variables['longitude'][:]

# All indices in bounding box:
where_j = np.where((lon >= 4.5) & (lon <= 5.4))[0]
where_i = np.where((lat >= 51.5) & (lat <= 52.45))[0]

# Start and end+1 indices in each dimension:
i0 = where_i[0]
i1 = where_i[-1]+1

j0 = where_j[0]
j1 = where_j[-1]+1

print(lat[i0:i1])  # [52.171 51.871 51.571]
print(lon[j0:j1])  # [4.527 4.827 5.127]
```

Now of course you have to slice each data array manually, using e.g. `var_slice = var[j0:j1, i0:i1]`

Comment: Just as a reference (in case it helps someone else), CDO can do these operation with just one command: `cdo sellonlatbox,4.5,5.4,51.5,52.45 model_fc.nc model_fc_slice.nc`